# JavaFx - increase space between text and tab header area edge

Tags: java, javafx

I can't understand what element I should work to do this task. I tried

```
.tab-header-area .tab{
    -fx-background-color:red;
    -fx-padding:30px;
}
```

**EDIT 1**
This is what I get
[image]

But I have the same tab header inside big red rectangle. How can I increase distance between text and edge of the tab  header area? By other words - how can I make tab header bigger with the same font size?

**EDIT 2**
When I do

```
.tab-header-area .tab .label{
    -fx-padding:5px 30px 5px 0;
}
.tab-header-area .tab {
    -fx-background-color: red ;
}
```

I get:
[image]

But I need (sorry, it's gimp,not photoshop)
[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of what it looks like, and (if possible) what you would like it to look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a border around the tab (not the label), you have to use this:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-padding: 20px;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
```

[image]

If you want to manipulate the tab-container (where the label is in) itself you need this:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab  > .tab-container{    
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
    -fx-padding: 20px;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Default for a selected tab is that:

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-width: 1, 1;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-faint-focus-color;
    -fx-border-insets: -4 -4 -6 -5, -2 -2 -5 -3;
    -fx-border-radius: 2, 1; /* looks sharper if outer border has a tighter radius (2 instead of 3) */
}
```

**And this it how it goes:**

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {    
    -fx-padding: 20px;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected {    
    -fx-padding: 20px;
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-border-color: black;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region >.tab:selected .focus-indicator{
    -fx-border-width: 0px;  
}
```

[image]

Look at the modena.css (default JavaFX stylesheet) file for info on things to change.

Font size will not change dynamic, you have to take care of font size with a listener on size/width/height property of the tab (in relation to font size).

And there are a lot of pseudo tags like .tab:selected .tab:top etc. So be aware of this kind of things if you want the default behavior only with new design.

And finally have a look at css selectors, you missed the descending selectors ('>'): http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

Comment: Rectangle is not custom rectangle it is focus rectangle.

Comment: I can't understand you code. In both codes there is a black border.Threre mustn't be any custom borders.

Comment: Sorry took longer than I thougt.

Comment: Thank you! Finally we did it!

Comment: Could you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690918/javafx-tab-rounded-corners

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you are looking for... maybe

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabPaneStyleTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        tab1.setGraphic(new Label("tab 1"));
        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        tab2.setGraphic(new Label("tab 2"));
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("tab-pane-big-tabs.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the css file

```
.tab-header-area .tab .label{
    -fx-padding:5px 30px 5px 0;
}
.tab-header-area .tab {
    -fx-background-color: red ;
}
```

Comment: But when tab is focused how can I make border be not in center but on the edge of tab header? I mean borders to behave the same way, only for big tab header?

Comment: I mean the main part must be not in center but it's wide must be ~wide of tab header. Text left, close button right.

Comment: Thank you for your help. See edit 2. I'm sorry, that I didn't draw it from the beginning. The main point how to increase the distance between border and text, but not the distance between border and the edge of the tab header.