# JavaFx: text-overflow:ellipsis analogue

Tags: java, javafx

I have a tab pane and I want all tab headers to have the same width. So I did:

```
.tab-header-area .tab{
    -fx-min-width:200;
    -fx-pref-width:200;
    -fx-max-width:200;
}
```

The problem is that if text is longer than the space it has than the label is messed with the close button. How can I make `.tab > .tab-container > .tab-label` cut the text and add "..." at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code option**:

```
TabPane pane = new TabPane();
pane.setTabMinWidth(200);
pane.setTabMaxWidth(200);
```

**Css Options**

```
.tab-pane{
    -fx-tab-min-width:200;
    -fx-tab-max-width:200;
}
```

[image]

*Old solution:*

> You have to set `-fx-max-width` for `.tab > .tab-container > .tab-label`  There are 2 options:
>
> 1) Set the default sizes for label and not tab (selected tab will be a little bit larger with `x` button
>   in it):
>
> ```
> .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab > .tab-container > .tab-label {
>     -fx-min-width:200;
>     -fx-pref-width:200;
>     -fx-max-width:200;
> }
> ```
>
> 2) Use your css and some smaller value for labels(This way all tabs
>   will be always 200 px):
>
> ```
> .tab-header-area .tab{
>     -fx-min-width:200;
>     -fx-pref-width:200;
>     -fx-max-width:200;
> }
>
> .tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab > .tab-container > .tab-label {
>    -fx-min-width:175;
>    -fx-pref-width:175;
>    -fx-max-width:175;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you. You again helped me, I will accept your question as soon as I try it. Could you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690918/javafx-tab-rounded-corners - it's very important for me but I can't solve it.

Comment: @iJava take a look one more time. I found out better solution)